# Flipped an array and reversing every second row

Tags: python, matrix

Basically I have a matrix in python 'example' (although much larger). I need to product the array 'example_what_I_want' with some python code. I guess a for loop is in order- but how can I do this?

```
example= 
[1,2,3,4,5],
[6,7,8,9,10],
[11,12,13,14,15],
[16,17,18,19,20],
[21,22,23,24,25]

example_what_I_want = 
[25,24,23,22,21],
[16,17,18,19,20],
[15,14,13,12,11],
[6,7,8,9,10],
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

So it increments in kind of snake fashion. And the first row must be reversed! and then follow that pattern.

thanks!

Comment: Is your `example` array actually a list of lists? Please try to edit so that your example code actually creates a proper Python object when run in a console, you're most of the way there already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming `example` is actually:

```
example = [[1,2,3,4,5],
           [6,7,8,9,10],
           [11,12,13,14,15],
           [16,17,18,19,20],
           [21,22,23,24,25]]
```

In which case you could do:

```
swapped_example = [sublst if idx%2 else sublst[::-1] for
                   idx,sublst in enumerate(example)][::-1]
```

Which will give you:

```
In [5]: swapped_example
Out[5]: 
[[25, 24, 23, 22, 21],
 [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [15, 14, 13, 12, 11],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but I suspect you might want to reverse at the outer layer rather than the inner layer. For example, try your current code with an **even** number of rows in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can use iter.

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],
[6,7,8,9,10],
[11,12,13,14,15],
[16,17,18,19,20],
[21,22,23,24,25]]

b = []

rev_a = iter(a[::-1])

while rev_a:
    try:
        b.append(rev_a.next()[::-1])
        b.append(rev_a.next())
    except StopIteration:
        break

print b
```

Modified (Did not know that earlier. @Adam),

```
a = iter(a)
while a:
    try:
        b.insert(0, a.next()[::-1])
        b.insert(0, a.next())
    except StopIteration:
        break

print b[::-1]
```